# "-bash: gcc: command not found" using cygwin when compiling c?

Tags: c, cygwin

I just installed the latest version of Cygwin ans for some reason when I try to compile code, it always flashes me this error:

-bash: gcc: command not

I also don't seem to have the gcc.exe that people are referring to and when I try installing stuff like mingw as suggested by other forum answers, it always gives me this error that ti couldn't install the repository.txt.... Looking for help on this matter!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can install gcc by running  setup-x86.exe or setup-x86_64.exe again. The gcc package is in the Devel category:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for late reply, I was at work and I just got home and did as you said and it worked!

Comment: I don't see those packages when I select Devel. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Daniel M: Did you open the installation from the local directory? You need to select from internet or it will only show those already installed.

Comment: just make sure to select gcc-core to add gcc.exe and not the 64Bit gcc core, since it didn't add the gcc.exe on my installation.

Answer (score 7):

Then you must go to System properties, System variables, and append the path to "C:\cygwin64\bin" in PATH

Comment: Wouldn't the installer do that for you?

Comment: didn't have to do that. installed it with the setup-x86.exe and the path was set.

Comment: Yup. things change

Answer (score 2):

If you have already added the gcc package you want you may also need to setup a symbolic link to a different gcc.exe binary.  For example:

```
$cd /usr/bin/
$ln -s i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe gcc
$which gcc
$/usr/bin/gcc
```

You can add the gcc package through the 'Add Package' batch file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Related issue.

I received below error:

'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Did the below to resolve:

1. Downloaded & installed setup-x86_64.exe from https://cygwin.com/install.html
2. selected below:
    gcc-g++: GNU Compiler Collection (C++)
    make: The GNU version of the 'make' utility
    gdb: The GNU Debugger
3. Appended ';C:\cygwin64\bin' to PATH environment variable

All errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

when selecting packages at installation or update search for 'gcc' in searchbox and select the boxes showing  'gcc' mostly found in devel package.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing cygwin from a mirror you did not use earlier(preferably the first one). Some of the servers hold older versions of cygwin which have many problems. Also, search for gcc and install the devel package.

I had the same problem when I installed cygwin from the iitm mirror(closest to my home), and it got resolved when I reinstalled the whole thing from the cygwin mirror.